# my computation of a real integral still has an imaginary number in it,

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have four residues that I have found.  I multiplied each by $2\pi i$, using the Residue Theorem.  But my final answer still has an $i$ in it.  Needless to say, it is not the right answer, since the goal was to compute a real integral on $R^+$

What should I do with the four residues to try and catch my mistake?  I've expanded each one in its Euler formula, $\cos(x) + i \sin(x)$, computed a common denominator, so that I can combine all residue terms.  This led to a few cancellations, but ultimately still left me with an $i$ factor.  Am I proceeding in generally the correct way?

Thanks,

EDIT: The integral is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2logx}{1+x^4}dx$$

Here's a summary of my work:  the integrand has simple poles at

$$e^{i\pi/4},e^{i3\pi/4},e^{i5\pi/4},e^{i7\pi/4}$$

and the residues are

$$-\frac{\pi}{16ie^{i\pi/4}},-\frac{3\pi}{16ie^{i3\pi/4}},-\frac{5\pi}{16ie^{i5\pi/4}},-\frac{7\pi}{16ie^{i7\pi/4}}$$

finally, multiplying each by $2\pi i$, and adding up the four terms gives me (incorrectly) $$-\frac{\pi^2i}{\sqrt{2}}$$ I added the terms by expanding out all of the Euler formulas, and then combined the terms with a common denominator.  I've checked my work about 5 times now...still can't catch my mistake...

Comment: a little more detail about the problem and your attempts at a solution  would be useful!

Comment: Could you please put the integral you are trying to compute into the problem?

Comment: Hi @gt6989b, ok I just did.

Comment: It might be useful to show the four residues and the final answer as well. Basically just do a brain-dump to the question text.

Comment: Hi @DavidHolden, ok, I'll add a little more detail now..

Comment: Hi @DavidK, ok, good idea.

Comment: The contour integral you end up computing in this problem is not a real number.

Comment: What contour are you using exactly?

Comment: Hi @CountIblis, hmm...really?  I have not moved on to try and give the estimates on the contour, which is a keyhole contour that encloses the four poles, but does not touch the positive real axis.  I was hoping to show that the integral goes to zero on the big and little circle, and then do something with the integral on the two straight lines that are approaching the positive real axis...

Comment: I was hoping that my answer is equal to the contribution of two integrals, both are integrals on straight lines approaching the positive real axis, from above and below.  And I think the estimate on the large and small circle is easy to do...

Comment: I don't understand what kind of paths on the complex plane you're using. You should describe them explicitly in your question. Anyway, the sort of paths I would use don't encircle all 4 poles, but only 1 or 2 of them.

Comment: The chosen contour must not enclose the branch point or corresponding branch cut for the complex logarithm.  Please refer to my solution to see one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will evaluate the integral

$$\color{blue}{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\log x}{x^4+1}dx}$$

by analyzing the integral $I$ defined as

$$I=\oint_C\frac{z^2(\log z)^2}{z^4+1}dz$$

where the contour $C$ is the keyhole contour for which the "key hole" is along the positive real axis.

The contributions to the integral from the circle of radius $R$ that enclosed the poles vanishes as $R\to \infty$.  Likewise, the contribution from the semi-circle with radius $\epsilon$ around the branch point at $z=0$ vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 (\log x)^2}{x^4+1}dx+\int_{\infty}^0\frac{x^2 (\log x+i2\pi)^2}{x^4+1}dx\\\\
&=-i4\pi \color{blue}{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\log x}{x^4+1}dx}+4\pi^2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+1} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

The first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is the integral of interest.  The second integral can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions and is equal to $\pi\sqrt{2}/4$.  We also have that $I$ is

$$I=2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^4 \text{Res}\left(\frac{z^2(\log z)^2}{z^4+1},z_k\right)$$

where $z_k=e^{i(2k-1)\pi/4}$, $k=1,2,3,4$, are the roots of $z^4=-1$.  The residues are given by

$$\frac{(\log z_k)^2}{4z_k}$$

Can you finish from here?
**SPOILER ALERT:**

> The sum of the residues, after pain-staking patience, are $\pi^2\sqrt{2}-i\frac{\pi^3\sqrt{2}}{4}$.  Thus, the integral of interest is $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\log x}{x^4+1}dx=\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{2}}{16}$$

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Please read the solution. The $(\log x)^2$ terms drop out.  We are left with the integral of interest.

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV - very interesting solution.  What was the motivation to look at $(log(z))^2$ instead of log(z), as given?  Is it a pretty well-known technique?  I certainly couldn't have thought of that myself.  Thanks so much...

Comment: @user258980 Thank you!  And you're welcome.  It was a real pleasure!!  As for the approach, if one tries integrating $(\log z)^1$ around a branch cut, the log part cancels and disappears.   So, we need to try another approach and one that works is to analyze the $(\log z)^2$ integral.  If we want to integrate $(\log x)^2$ we need to analyze $(\log z)^3$ in the complex plane.  The $(\log x)^3$ part drops out and we are left with $3(2\pi i)(\log x)^2$, $3(2\pi i)^2\,(\log x)^1$, and $(2\pi i)^3$ terms.  Kind of neat, huh?

Answer (score 0):

The following is an outline of the solution which is the most natural in my opinion.

Write$$A:=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\log x}{1+x^4}dx.$$A short calculation shows that$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^2\log x}{1+x^4}dx=A+i\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt=A+i\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=A+\frac{i\pi^2}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$(the second left hand integral can be evaluated using either complex integration or standard real analysis methods).

Now consider paths which go along the whole real line with a small circular "jump" to avoid $0$, then draw a semicircle in the upper half plane. The contribution of the semicircle vanishes at infinite radius, and the contribution of the circular jump vanishes at $0$ radius. The integral$$\int_\gamma\frac{z^2\log z}{1+z^4}dz$$along the above described kind of path can be evaluated by considering the residues at the two upper poles of the function.

Comment: Hi @amitaiYuval, it sounds like you are integrating straight through the branch cut, which I assume you've chosen the positive real axis as your cut?   If so, is it a valid move?  I feel we should consider paths *near* the whole real line, and let the paths approach $R^+$ ...thanks

Comment: No, dear @user258980, I'm integrating along the *whole* real line, and avoiding the origin by a small semicircle from $(-\epsilon,0)$ to $(\epsilon,0)$. This tiny semicircle is in the upper half plane, as is the large semicircle, and hence the origin is *not* inside the whole path. I'm using the branch of the $\log$ function which is real on the positive real ray and defined on the upper half plane.